# Failed to notify recipient {email <>} defined in app argocd/<>: notification service 'email' is not supported"

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I have an app deployed using ArgoCD, I want to trigger email notifications once the deployment is successful.

I read about email notifications in argocd docs https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/notifications/ and have performed all the steps mentioned.

I have applied the patch for argocd-notification-cm

```
kubectl patch cm argocd-notifications-cm -n argocd --type merge -p '{"data": {"service.email": "{ username: test, password: test, host: my-smtp-host, port: my-smtp-port, from: test@test.com }" }}'
```

Subscribed for notification using,

```
kubectl patch app app1 -n argocd -p '{"metadata": {"annotations": {"notifications.argoproj.io/subscribe.on-sync-succeeded.email":"myemail@test.com"}}}' --type merge
```

In the argocd-notification-cm I have defined as below

```
data:
  service.email: |
    host: my-smpt-host
    port: my-smpt-port
    username: test
    password: test
    from: test@test.com
```

and the subscription notification as

```
annotations:
 notifications.argoproj.io/subscribe.on-sync-succeeded.email: myemail@test.com
```

However I am not getting any mails and facing below error in the controller.

```
Failed to notify recipient {email myemail@test.com} defined in app argocd/app1: notification service 'email' is not supported" app=argocd/app1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with the changes as below,

Have updated the configMap as

```
data:
  service.email.gmail:
```

and the subscription annotation as

```
annotations:
 notifications.argoproj.io/subscribe.on-sync-succeeded.gmail
```

since 'email' is not part of subscription notification service I was facing the error, after updating it to 'gmail' the issue got resolved and emails are getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

**Seems Failed to parse new settings¶**

```
error converting YAML to JSON¶
```

Correct YAML syntax:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-notifications-cm
data:
  service.slack: |
    token: $slack-token
    icon: ":rocket:"
```

**service type 'xxxx' is not supported¶**

You need to check your argocd-notifications controller version. For instance, the teams integration is to `support v1.1.0 and more`.

**Failed to notify recipient¶**

notification service 'xxxx' is not supported"¶

You have not defined xxxx in argocd-notifications-cm or to fail to parse settings.

Please go through the `argocd-notifications` binary includes a set of CLI commands that helps to configure the controller settings and [troubleshoot issues](https://argocd-notifications.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/#failed-to-notify-recipient).

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community. Let me know if you need any further support.